# Ruby on Rails - passing hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have a piece of controller code where some values are calculated. The result is in the form of an array of hashes. This needs to get into a partial form somehow so that it may be retrieved later during commit (which is through the Submit button).

The questions is how do we pass the array of hashes?
thanks.

Comment: can you show us the code please?

Comment: As per my understanding you want to pass array of hashes through html form submit.right???

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason it *has* to be through the form? This is the type of thing I usually use the session for.

I can't really think of a nice way to do what you're asking with forms. I guess you could create hidden fields for each key in your hash in the form with [hidden_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag) as an alternative. Then you run into problems translating it (what if a key's value is an array or another hash?).

You could easily store the hash in the session and then on each page load, check to see if there is a hash where you expect it. On calculating values:

```
session[:expected_info] = results
```

And each page load, something like this:

```
if session.has_key?(:expected_info)
  results = session.delete(:expected_info)
  # you already calculated the results, just grab them and
  # do what you need to do
else
  # you don't have the expected info 
end
```

Comment: thanks for your responses. I had (earlier) tried the Session based approach and i was not satisfied primarily because it wasn't a generic solution that could all of the scenarios. It does have limitations and dependencies which is when i sought for more ideas.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to pass it as a string to your partial:

```
[{}].inspect
```

and eval it when it is submitted back through the form:

```
eval("[{}]"))
```

but that would be really dirty…

Comment: This will leave your app completely open to attack if a user wants to modify the html of the form before submitting it.  You really can't trust a user's input to be run.  Also, even if you wanted to take this approach, you would have to deal with escaping the `.inspect` string just so it didn't break the form if it had quotes or other characters.